# Small Simple Local Data Store for keeping user settings

Tags: c#, datastore

I have this tiny C# winforms application that will NOT grow larger in any way.
It's just two input fields and a button.

I want to know if you guys have knowledge of a way to **store** the **values** that a user inputs **in a local datastore**. You may consider 10 records to be a lot of data for this scenario.

**Requirements**

1. It shouldn't require any setup from the database side. (table creation, etc)
2. I should be able to just give it an object and it should store it, I don't want to waste time on that.
3. The data needs to be fairly easily retrievable.
4. I want to be able to reuse this thing for every small app I create like this.

**My Ideas**

1. A POCO object that will be XML-Serialized and saved to the Local Settings folder. Upon loading of the app, this file is deserialized back into the POCO object.
2. An OODBMS: I have no experience with these but I always thought they consisted of a single dll so it would be easy to package them with the program.
3. I once, a long long time ago, built an application that stored user settings inside the registry. Don't know if that is still appreciated though.

**What do you think is the best approach?**

Code samples are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken both answers into account and built the following:

```
public static class IsolatedStorageExtensions
{
    public static void SaveObject(this IsolatedStorage isoStorage, object obj, string fileName)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream writeStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(writeStream, obj);
        writeStream.Flush();
        writeStream.Close();
    }

    public static T LoadObject<T>(this IsolatedStorage isoStorage, string fileName)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        T readData = (T)formatter.Deserialize(readStream);
        readStream.Flush();
        readStream.Close();

        return readData;
    }
}
```

A wrapper POCO object that contains that data to be serialized:

```
[Serializable]
internal class DataStoreContainer
{
    public DataStoreContainer()
    {
        UserIDs = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> UserIDs { get; set; }
}
```

To consume these extensions:

```
private IsolatedStorageFile _isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
private DataStoreContainer _data = new DataStoreContainer();
private const string FILENAME = "MyAppName.dat";
```

And in any method where you want to get the data :

```
_data = _isoStore.LoadObject<DataStoreContainer>(FILENAME);
```

To save the data:

```
_isoStore.SaveObject(_data, FILENAME);
```

Comment: I seem to remember us having problems in our project around isolated storage when we upped the version number of the app. I may be wrong, but I don't think the settings are automatically copied when you up version numbers. You might want to test for this if this is a scenario in your app(s).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Because this is such a small application I'm not versioning it. I do plan on using this method for future apps so I've added your note as a comment to my library :-)

Comment: Great solution for small projects, really helped me out and saved a load of time too, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?  It stores data in a local file, specific to that user (or to the application, depending on how you specify).  You can easily serialize objects to and from the store because it's stream-based.  It sounds like the perfect solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you state 10 items would be a lot I would vote for #1 or a variation of #1, Binary serialized... you don't seem to indicate that being able to read the data is important and binary data should give you smaller file sizes, though if 10 is a lot this still shouldn't be important.

That being said I enjoy what I've seen of db4objects.